# how to provide Cell optional type from react-table in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, react-table

How can I handle the Cell optional type from react-tabe? I am using react-table package to build my table data. based on react-table api [react-table api #column-options](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options)

```
Cell: Function | React.Component => JSX
Optional
Defaults to ({ value }) => String(value)
Receives the table instance and cell model as props
Must return valid JSX
This function (or component) is primarily used for formatting the column value, eg. If your column accessor returns a date object, you can use a Cell function to format that date to a readable format.
```

I use function call under `Cell` and set the Cell type as option function,

```
export interface CellData {
  [key: string]: any;
}
export type Data = Column<CellData> & { Cell ? : Function};
```

but I have this error under ts check

```
src/meta/table/Columns.test.tsx:5:9 - error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

5         data.Cell({
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/meta/table/Columns.test.tsx:10:20 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'Function | (string & Function) | (number & Function) | (ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> & Function) | (ReactNodeArray & Function) | (ComponentClass<...> & Function) | (Function...' are callable.
    Type 'Function' has no call signatures.

10         data.Cell({
                       ~~~~
```

Comment: Hi - did you sort the issue? I have kinda od similar problem, where i would like to add extra property to the cell definition.

Comment: no, mind provide your solution?